# Digital Asset Links file not found

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать имплементацию диплинк

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

Я сделал все точно как в видео шаг за шагом

Но это не работает

По видео в шаге 3-ем когда я нажимаю на кнопку `Link and Verify` я получаю вот такаю ошибку

[image]

Но если я пробую открыть эту ссылку в браузере то я вижу свой файл

[image]

В чем может быть проблема?

Если что то нужно добавить говорите